# How to update a module or function which is bundled using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

At many times breakpoint would not be sufficient to debug issue in production (compressed & minified code), so I would update a function with patched code to debug/test functionality. How can I do the same if my code is bundled via webpack? Is there any method like this? `updateModule(modulename, function(){//patchedcode})`

Note: I am using ES6 import syntax to require modules (ignore if this info is not related)

Comment: If you are packing for production then surely you have development branch/environment where it's not packed - you should maybe fix the bug there and reintroduce to production

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DarrenSweeney But, I am interested in live patch update, for example when I am using live site if I run into some issue, I will check it by updating the module.